# Trapped region in segmented image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have segmented a medical image into two classes, namely class 1 (epidermis of the skin) and class 2 (dermis of the skin).  I want to detect if there is any class 2 (dermis of the skin) trapped inside or completely surrounded by class 1 (epidermis of the skin). Is there any image processing library function or numpy function which can help me achieve this? If anyone knows any other logic using using numpy fucntions please share that too.

[image: The lighter dermis region can be seen trapped inside the darker epidermis region. I have already segmented the image to denote the epidermis as 1 and dermis as 2 and stored it in a 2D array with size equal to that of the original image]

Comment: Sharing a sample image can help

Comment: I have added an image along with the description of the image.

Comment: There are no functions to achieve this directly. You will have to look into some segmentation methods after sufficient preprocessing

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could suggest me some methods.

Comment: Can you help us understand what is dermis and what is epidermis in the image?

Comment: The lighter region is the dermis and the darker region is the epidermis.